# Google Maps api v3を使ってプレイスライブラリを導入しようとしているのですがエラーがでます。

Tags: javascript, html5, api

いろいろなサイトのサンプル参考にしているのですがエラーがでます。

apiブートストラップ URL の libraries パラメータでのライブラリの読み込みは書いています。その他にもapiが足りていないのか。やgoogleのリファレンスを読んで同じ書き方をしているのですがエラーが出ます。

エラー：Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlacesService' of undefined
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このエラーが消えません。

Comment: 特に参考にしていたサイトはこちらです。
http://phpjavascriptroom.com/?t=ajax&p=googlemapsapiv3_lib_places

Answer (score 1):

> エラー：Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PlacesService' of undefined

`google.maps.places`が`undefined`になっているようです。

原因は2点考えられます。

(1)Google Maps API の読み込み時にplacesライブラリが有効になっていない
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places
ではなく
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true
などとしている？
でも

> apiブートストラップ URL の libraries パラメータでのライブラリの読み込みは書いています。

とありますね……。
一応スペルの確認をした方がよいのかもしれません。
（placesがplaceになっていないか？等）

(2)google.maps.places にundefinedなものを代入している

```
google.maps.places = undefined;
```

ちょっと考えにくいですが、上記のようなことをどこかでしていれば、エラーは再現します。

---

(1)も(2)も決め手には欠ける気がします……。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
(1)を確認しましたがGoogle Maps API の読み込み時のスペルミスはありませんでした。あと私のプログラムはweb上での使用を予定していますので、sensor=falseにしています。


(2)の内容ですが大域変数でserviceを宣言しています。　　

メソッドの自体は関数の中で宣言しています。
　　service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
　　service.Search(request, callback);
これだけ書いても仕方ないですがいちおう書いておきます。
他に思いたることといえば関数の呼び出す順番で何かが干渉しているか。